# Supremum, Infinimum, Fractions, And Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ is a metric space and $f$ and $g$ are functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$ and $\displaystyle \inf_{x \in X} |g(x)|$ exists, and we have that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} \leq 1$ where $g(x) \neq 0$, can we conclude that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} = \frac{\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|}{\displaystyle \inf_{x \in X} |g(x)|}$?
 Can we therefore conclude that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| \leq \inf_{x \in X} |g(x)|$?

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $X = \mathbb{R}, f = \exp(-2|x|), g = \exp(-|x|).$ Clearly $\sup f = 1, \inf g = 0, \sup f/g = 1,$ but $\sup f / \inf g = \infty.$ AFAIK, the most you can say in general is that $\sup |f/g| \le \sup |f|/ \inf |g| $ (why?).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 i feel like you should specify that why "why?" is applying to the inequality you said you can show, and not "the most you can say" aspect

Comment: @mathworker21 I did mean it that way, but on reflection, I think it applies to the most you can say part as well (in the generic situation) - consider a $g$ s.t. $|g|$ is constant.

Comment: I have another question: Can we say that $\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|}{\displaystyle \sup_{x \in X} |g(x)|} \leq \sup_{x \in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$?